# Modify customer created_at date using customer_save_before event

Tags: magento-enterprise, customer, customer-attribute

I am trying to update the customer created_at (customer since) date due to some weird issues but not able to do so.
I have used the following code:

**Registering Event:**

```
<frontend>
    ...
    <events>
        <customer_save_before>
            <observers>
                <magepsycho_customer_customer_save_before>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>magepsycho_customer/observer</class>
                    <method>customerSaveBefore</method>
                </magepsycho_customer_customer_save_before>
            </observers>
        </customer_save_before>            
    </events>
    ...
</frontend>
```

**Observer Model:**

```
public function customerSaveBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $event      = $observer->getEvent();
    $customer   = $event->getCustomer();

    if ($customer->isObjectNew()) {            

        //@fix for date issue where day and months are interchanged (esp if registered by bots)
        //get magento UTC date
        $mageDate = $customer->getCreatedAt(); //but this value is always empty
        $mageMon  = date('m', strtotime($customer->getCreatedAt()));
        $mageDay  = date('d', strtotime($customer->getCreatedAt()));

        //get pure UTC date
        $currentMon = date('m');
        $currentDay = date('d');

        if ($currentDay != $mageDay || $currentMon != $mageMon) {
            //set the fixed date
            $fixedDate = now();
            $customer->setCreatedAt($fixedDate);
        }
    }
}
```

But main issue is `$customer->getCreatedAt()` is always empty.
Not sure if the event is triggered earlier then the date is set.

Comment: ever solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are right about "Not sure if the event is triggered earlier then the date is set." here is code snippet of `save()` method of class `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`. Customer model class extends this class.

```
$this->_beforeSave();
if ($this->_dataSaveAllowed) {
      $this->_getResource()->save($this);
      $this->_afterSave();
}
```

Here `_beforeSave()` method fires event `customer_save_before`. I think `_getResource()` method hits db and save customer to db.

So try `customer_save_after` event which fires at `_afterSave()` there you may have `created_at` attribute value.

Comment: If you use customerSaveAfter event it will go infinite loop due to recursive call.

Comment: Well then If you want to manipulate data at the time of registration, use `customer_register_success` event, which also fires after `save()` method, and I guess `updated_at` attribute will change on every save action not `created_at`.

Comment: Well the account can be created from checkout page also so this event wont work in that case. customer_register_success event is triggered only if user is registered from customer/account/create link

Comment: I found this event for checkout, you may have to  hook at this event also, `checkout_submit_all_after` This event will give you `$order` and `$quote` you can get `customer` from them and `created_id` for customer as well. I don't If this bit late or not for you, at this moment quote is converted to order and new customer email is sent( if registration happens ).

Comment: Main thing is I have to use a singly entry method for modifying the created_at date as customer can register from custom popups, custom landing page, normal registration form, checkout page etc. So I have to find some event similar to customer_save_before.

Comment: Well, I can suggest some work around, you can go with `customer_save_after` and set some flag type attribute that tell you that you have already modified `create_at` date while you save `$customer` and check it on top of your observer method, so you can break infinite loop.